# Reading from a text file and changing the strings to int's to be entered in arrays is not working

Tags: java

Basically I am asking for the filename with a method called CS160Input (provided by my instructor) to ask for the filename. The text document has a bunch of entries each on their own lines, and I am trying to assign each number to a place in an array, but I am failing to actually write to the array. I know it is finding the file, because when i print out the counter, it tells me the correct amount of lines in the file. But when I try to print out a place in the array, I tried index 3 as you can see in my code, and it gives me 0 regardless of what I try. I tried creating an array of strings first and I ended up getting null for each index value as well.

```
public static void caclulate() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName = CS160Input.readString("Please enter the name of the file: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
        int value, counter = 0;
        int array[] = null;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            sc.nextLine();
            counter++;
        }
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        int[] calcArray = new int [counter];
        int i = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
           calcArray[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(calcArray[3]);
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of `value` and `array`? You are not using these variables.

Comment: The code works fine for me (on a file with one integer per line).  By the way, the method name is misspelled (`c` and `l` are transposed).

Comment: Your file perhaps has non-integer values in-between the integers, which will make `hasNextInt()` return false.

Comment: Change the code at the end to `System.out.println(i);` to see if i is incremented.

Comment: @Gendarme You are a hero. I was writing to the file in a previous program, and the written numbers were doubles with 2 decimal places, so hasNextInt() was returning false just like you said. Once I changed to hasNextDouble() it was fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gendarme pointing out that hasNextInt() could be spitting out false if there were values in between, it made me take a closer look and I realized that in a previous program the numbers being written to the text file were doubles with 2 decimal places. Once I changed to hasNextDouble(), the program worked as intended.